# Batch convert ISO/WAV/CUE back into BIN/CUE

Tags: command-line, iso, data-cd, file-format, audio-cd

I've been looking for a command utility/script that does the opposite of bchunck, but can't seem to find one.

What bchunck does is taking a mixed-mode CD image in BIN/CUE format and separate it into a set of ISO and music tracks (either CDR or WAV). I want to use a tool to reverse the process.

I can do this with a Windows utility like CDmage under WINE, or following [this guide](https://github.com/recalbox/recalbox-os/wiki/Convert-iso-track-wav-bin-to-bin-cue-(EN)) (also dependent on WINE or Windows), but I'd love a way to automate the process and use it natively on Linux.

---

Here's what I tried so far. Let's say I have a Mixed-mode CD test image with 1 data track and 4 music tracks, IMAGE.bin and IMAGE.cue, generated from a physical CD:

```
cdrdao read-cd --datafile IMAGE.bin --driver generic-mmc:0x20000 --device /dev/cdrom --read-raw IMAGE.toc
toc2cue IMAGE.toc IMAGE.cue
```

If I do `bchunk -v -w IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue track` it outputs the following files:

track01.iso

track02.wav

track03.wav

track04.wav

track05.wav

Now to try to put the image back together:

First I convert track01.iso back to the BIN format using the [PowerISO Linux tool](https://www.poweriso.com/download.php) with `./poweriso convert track01.iso -o IMAGE-NEW.bin -ot bin`. Note that a IMAGE-NEW.cue is generated, but it doesn't contain any music track information, so it should be discarded, and the original IMAGE.cue be used instead.

Secondly, I convert the WAV files back to RAW and concatenate them to IMAGE-NEW.bin:

```
avconv -i trackC02.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC03.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC04.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
avconv -i trackC05.wav -f s16le -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le - >> IMAGE-NEW.bin
```

IMAGE-NEW.bin, together with the original IMAGE.cue seem to be working fine as a Mixed-mode CD image. However, if I do `diff IMAGE.bin IMAGE-new.bin` it outputs that they are different, so I'm not sure if this method I came up with is the correct one, or if this is a consequence of both images being generated using different methods.

That said, if I do `bchunk -v -w IMAGE-NEW.bin IMAGE.cue track-new` and diff all `track` and `track-new` files to each other, they are indeed identical. I don't have enough experience with comparing binaries to know if I'm doing this right and why IMAGE.bin IMAGE-new.bin are different.